# Port forwarding does not work under any circunstance

Tags: networking, firewall, port-forwarding

I am trying to get a minecraft server to work and its all fine in my local network, but as soon as I try to connect from the outside world it won't do it. To explain my setup: I am 101% sure that port forwardind is setup correctly on my router settings(inbound port 25565, TCP/UDC,local port 25565 and local PC IP), Firewall exceptions and static local IP are set on Windows, followed a detailed tutorial on configuring the server itself and I have a different machine on a different network attemptiong to connect to the server on my public ip, it always times out. I used many different port checking sites and got 3 differnt results: Filtered, Closed and Stealth. I went as far as putting the server PC on a DMZ and completely disabling Windows Firewall, only to have the same results Am I missing something obvious? It feels like I went through every possible varible and nothing works.

Comment: If you put the host in the DMZ with no firewall and you could not connect to it, then the problem seems to be at the router. One way to check it, run a sniffer on the host, like `wireshark` and see if you receive the packets the router should be forwarding.

Comment: What is the external IP address reported by your router? My guess is your connection is behind Carrier Grade NAT.

Comment: Run a web server on port 80 and map that and test it with a web browser. Make sure that works first. Check with your ISP about what ports they filter. If you look in your router's management UI for its WAN IP address and compare it to what whatsmyip.org reports, is it the same?